# Mutate a column based on dataset name

Tags: r

Can anyone please suggest how to mutate a new column based on dataset name? Below is my code:

```
WK20 <- data.frame(cbind(c("A","B","C","D","E"),c("135373","135530","72082","100029","19719"), c("484576.90","476355.44","249807.60","354968.68","67386.69")),stringsAsFactors = F)

WK20 <- WK20 %>%
rename("STORE ID" = X1,
     "TOTAL UNIT" = X2,
     "TOTAL SALES" = X3) %>%
melt(id="STORE ID") %>% 
mutate(WK = names(data.frame()))
```

The expected output is to have the name of dataset in object of WK. I run the code and get the error "Error: Column `WK` must be length 10 (the number of rows) or one, not 0".

Expected output is:

[image]

Comment: What do you intend to happen with `names(data.frame())`? You're creating an empty data frame

Comment: I edited the question. Thanks for notifying me.

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question (not sure if its possible), but if the goal is to bind after multiple dataframes and this column is used to remember where each row comes from, this easiest way to do that is to create a list of dataframes and use `bind_rows` function with `.id` argument

Comment: Maybe you need this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560389/get-name-of-dataframe-passed-through-pipe-in-r

Comment: Please try `substitute(WK20)` or `quote(WK20)`. It gives a symbol then do `deparse` around to get a string