# How to get a function input name in R whilst using pipes

Tags: r, magrittr

I am trying to capture the name of the input variable as a character string. This is fairly easy using `match.call()` however this doesn't work when using magrittr's pipes. Wondering if there is any easy modification that would get it to work within pipes as well as if the function was called normally?

```
library(magrittr)
myfun <- function(fun){
    print(match.call()$fun %>% as.character())
}

myfun(mean)
mean %>% myfun

myfun(iris)
iris %>% myfun
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get name of dataframe passed through pipe in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560389/get-name-of-dataframe-passed-through-pipe-in-r)

Comment: `iris %>% {parent.frame(5)$lhs} %>% as.character`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the pipe operator `%>%` pass the input variable name as dot `"."` to the next function, but you can control the output from the pipe operator `lhs` to pass you the actual name of the input variable instead of dot in your function. See the below function ( edited to work with/without `%>%`)

```
myfun <- function(x) {
  x <- substitute(x)

 if (x !="."){
 print(deparse(x))
 }else{

  i <- 1
  while(!("chain_parts" %in% ls(envir=parent.frame(i))) && i < sys.nframe()) {
    i <- i+1
  }
  ee <- parent.frame(i)
  print(deparse(ee$lhs))
  }
}

mean %>% myfun()
[1] "mean"

myfun(mean)
[1] "mean"
```

Hope it helps. 
-Ahmed Alhendi

Comment: Thank you for the answer, whilst this solution works in the piped case, it doesn't appear to work in the regular case, i.e. `myfun(mean)`

Comment: I edited the above fun, it should work with/without `%>%`