# How to pass the name of the dataframe to write_csv in dplyr

Tags: r

I would like to write a dataframe with the name of the dataframe passed to the `write_csv` function. For example, I would normally do the following

```
iris %>% write_csv("iris.csv")
```

but I would like to not have to write the name of the file. I tried something like the following

```
iris %>% write_csv(paste0(., ".csv"))
```

but I think this will require something more like a quosure

Comment: The result of that code is `..csv` not `iris.csv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define your own custom `write.csv3`:

```
write.csv3 <- function(x, ...) {
  write.csv(x, file = paste0(deparse(substitute(x)), '.csv'), ...)
}
write.csv3(iris)
```

If you want to use pipes then you could set an attribute `name` first:

```
write.csv3 <- function(x, ...) {
  write.csv(x, file = paste0(attr(x, "name"), '.csv'), ...)
}

attr(iris, "name") <- "iris" 
iris %>% write.csv3
```

Or you try to apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30061286/1777111) hacky approach.

Comment: This does work, but I have not been able to pipe to `write.csv3`

Comment: Ok I see. Updated my answer. But there is no *easy* way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The basic use case of function parameter in a dplyr pipe is to treat function parameter as a name something like this:

```
csv_save <- function(xx){
  csv_name = as.name(xx)
  iris %>% write.csv(.,file = !!csv_name)
}

csv_save("files.csv")
```

(not tested)